# OpenEDX CMS, we're having trouble rendering your component

Tags: django, openedx

I have manually installed the full OpenEdx stack, but when trying to edit an existing unit (creating one works), I get the following error:
[image]

Here is the exception stack from the logs:

```
Oct  3 16:47:51 ip-xxx [service_variant=cms][contentstore.views.preview][env:sandbox] WARNING [ip-xxx  17550] [preview.py:318] - Unable to render author_view for <VerticalBlockWithMixins @9018 graded=False, annotation_token_secret=u'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', hide_after_due=False, giturl=None, edxnotes=False, source_file=None, course_edit_method=u'Studio', default_tab=None, children=[BlockUsageLocator(CourseLocator(u'Company', u'TD101', u'2018', None, None), u'html', u'8ca5de5b3eae4d95bae0df2c4c67ccce')], in_entrance_exam=False, showanswer=u'finished', display_name=u'Unit', video_speed_optimizations=True, graceperiod=None, format=None, due=None, start=datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 3, 17, 11, tzinfo=tzutc()), xml_attributes={u'filename': [u'vertical/693fb3e8136844e7a3e8c844ece0c0ae.xml', u'vertical/693fb3e8136844e7a3e8c844ece0c0ae.xml']}, days_early_for_beta=None, visible_to_staff_only=False, parent=BlockUsageLocator(CourseLocator(u'Company', u'TD101', u'2018', None, None), u'sequential', u'd7f0672550ec45f9adb6a3e504b6c8fc'), tags=[], matlab_api_key=None, xqa_key=None, is_entrance_exam=False, annotation_storage_url=u'http://your_annotation_storage.com', use_latex_compiler=False, video_bumper={}, show_correctness=u'always', static_asset_path=u'', hide_from_toc=False, show_reset_button=False, name=None, group_access={}, video_auto_advance=False, rerandomize=u'never', user_partitions=[], chrome=None, edxnotes_visibility=True, position=None, max_attempts=None, self_paced=False>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/cms/djangoapps/contentstore/views/preview.py", line 316, in get_preview_fragment
    fragment = module.render(preview_view, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/core.py", line 202, in render
    return self.runtime.render(self, view, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/x_module.py", line 1903, in render
    return self.__getattr__('render')(block, view_name, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/x_module.py", line 1310, in render
    return super(MetricsMixin, self).render(block, view_name, context=context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xblock/runtime.py", line 812, in render
    updated_frag = self.wrap_xblock(block, view_name, frag, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/x_module.py", line 1262, in wrap_xblock
    frag = wrapper(block, view, frag, context)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/lib/xblock_utils/__init__.py", line 259, in replace_static_urls
    static_asset_path=static_asset_path
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/static_replace/__init__.py", line 218, in replace_static_urls
    return process_static_urls(text, replace_static_url, data_dir=static_asset_path or data_directory)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/static_replace/__init__.py", line 130, in process_static_urls
    text
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/static_replace/__init__.py", line 122, in wrap_part_extraction
    return replacement_function(original, prefix, quote, rest)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/static_replace/__init__.py", line 188, in replace_static_url
    url = staticfiles_storage.url(rest)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 162, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/openedx/core/djangoapps/theming/storage.py", line 180, in _url
    return super(ThemeCachedFilesMixin, self)._url(hashed_name_func, processed_asset_name, force, hashed_files)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 141, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/edx/app/edxapp/venvs/edxapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 376, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("The name '%s' could not be hashed with %r." % (name, self))
ValueError: The name 'bundles/js/factories/xblock_validation.788ba995ff95.js' could not be hashed with <openedx.core.storage.ProductionStorage object at 0x7f524dd4b290>.
```

Any idea how to solve that, it seems to be an issue inside Django, but I can't find any information about it.

Comment: What type of unit? like Video unit, HTML block or 3-rd party x-Block?

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne All the kinds (but we mainly, use HTML), just tested it with video and it does the same, I can edit everything when creating it, but if I leave the page and come back I get this error message.

Comment: As you can see, the error is with cache storage. 
Are you using pre-cached  "xblock_validation.788ba995ff95.js" URL? 
if yes, remove it and compile static files again.

Comment: Did this ever get a result, I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry did not find a solution, we decided to got with an hosted solution instead.